# Kohana HABTM self join

Tags: php, sql, kohana

I have a problem with using the ORM and creating a has and belongs to many self join using Kohana 2.3.4

I have this table

### Tasks

ID | Title | etc......

I need to be able to link tasks to other tasks, a task can have multiple children, and multiple parents. So I was thinking of having this table.

### Tasks_Tasks

ID | task_1_id | task_2_id

To link the tasks to each other, but I can't work out in Kohana how to set the foreign keys correctly for the relationships, or if it is possible at all?

Can anyone suggest an answer? Or even better, a better solution?

Comment: Kohana 2.4 hasn't actually been released yet, so you'd get better luck asking on the Kohana forum and IRC room.

Comment: Hi thank for your answer, you're right, I am using 2.3.4

Answer (score 0):

Instead of extending ORM you should be extending ORM_Tree.  This is built for just this type of relationship.  Take a look at system/libraries/ORM_Tree.php.